# how to integrate jsx/react snippets in html on sublime3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am new to sublime.I have installed sublime plugins-html snippets and reactjs snippets.I was trying to use jsxt as mentioned here

http://hackersome.com/p/joemaddalone/ReactSublimeSnippets

in sample index.html which does not pop snippet.

How to bring up the React JSX script type in html by just typing jstx in sublime as shown in the video

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-hello-world-first-component.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Majority of the shortcuts available in this snippet is scoped to .js file, that mean it meant to be available only in .js files.

Few shortcuts doesn't scoped to any file type eg: jsxt will print `<script type="text/jsx"> </script>` in any file.

If you need to know which are available in html file, check this github repo. https://github.com/joemaddalone/ReactSublimeSnippets/tree/master/snippets

Comment: Yeah! I agree.But even jsxt is not working in my sublime.